# What is the family theme piano song in "Legend of the Blue Sea"?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, piano, korean

Trying to find the name of the family theme from the *Legend of the Blue Sea* television series. This soundtrack is unfortunately not in the soundtrack list.

[This link](http://youtu.be/3Fl1bvH7LMk?t=93) directs to the relevant scene in the show where you can hear the track.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question which theme you are looking for, but what seems to be a complete soundtrack listing is in the Wikipedia article:

> "Love Story"   Kim Jang-woo Kim Ji-hyang
>   "A World That Is You" (그대라는 세상) Han Joo Lee Yoo-jin Yoon Mi-rae
>   "Lean on You" (너에게 기울어가)    Kim Ji-hyang
>   "Shy Boy" (설레이는 소년처럼)   Shin Hae-chul
>   "Somewhere Someday" (어디선가 언젠가)  Kim Eana
>   "Wind Flower" (바람꽃)
>   "Fool" (바보야)    Honey Pot
>   "Why Would I Do Like This" (내가 왜 이럴까)   Noh Ah-ram (Coffee Boy) Noh
>   "Day By Day" (하루에 하나씩)
>   "If Only" (만에 하나)
>   "Love Road" (사랑길)   Kim Ji-hyang
>   "Sound Of Ocean"    Ryo Yoshimata   Ryo Yoshimata
>   "Memories"  Yoshimata   Yoshimata
>   "The Last Time" Yoshimata   Yoshimata
>   "Hidden Story" (숨겨진 이야기)    Second Moon
>   "My Name" (나의 이름)       Second Moon
>   "The Way to Meet You" (너를 찾아 가는길)   Second Moon
>   "At This Time" (다음 이시간에)
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Blue_Sea

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the soundtrack that I am looking for is not on this list. I pasted a link to the relevant scene from the drama.